# What is momentum factor and how is it calculated based on three parameters?

Tags: portfolio-management, technical-analysis, momentum

I have 7 year prices of a group of stocks and index prices for the same time period now I want to calculate momentum factor, depending on the three relevant parameters (rebalancing frequency, rolling window, proportion of the universe to trade).

Does anyone have any relevant examples or paper?

Comment: For example: every month (frequency) you form a portfolio based on last 6 month returns (rolling window), the long portfolio contains the top 10% (proportion) and the short portfolio contains the bottom 10% of stocks.

Comment: Fama French compute the Momentun Factor as follows https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/det_mom_factor.html